# Why have SSD-based *new* Eee PCs diappeared?

Tags: ssd, netbook, eee-pc

I have been looking for an SSD-based *new* Eee PC netbook (silence is more important to me than capacity) and was surprised to discover that they are no longer being offered by major retailers.

Any idea why is that?

Has a fundamental flaw in the the SSD technology been discovered? Something else?

Comment: Maybe a completely _new_ Eee PC will be available soon? - So the stock for the _old new_ ones is low. Just an assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that many people complaint about high pricing and low capacity of the SSD models. Think of the most common user who wants to save a bunch of movies and music titles on their Eee PC, they won't be very happy with ~32GB.
I own an Eee PC (1015P) on my own. First I was a bit puzzled about the fact they are not using a SSD in it, but the large amount of space really comes in handy. A 5400 RPM hard drive is not very noisy, too.

Comment: I think the main complaint with the early SSDs in the EEE PC was the [performance problems](http://gadgetmix.com/netbook/asus-eee-s101-ssd-performance-not-too-shabby-netbook/) with the [JMicron controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMicron#SSD_Controllers).

Comment: @sblair & @Michael K -- excellent points. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I am in the market for an SSD-based netbook (doesn't have to be Eee PC necessarily). If you can recommend one, that would be super! :)